# How to call a Java entrypoint method with non-primitive types as parameters from C++ using GraalVM

Tags: java, c++, visual-c++, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I am trying to create a shared library(dll with header and lib files) of a java code using graalvm.

there will be one java method with 2 parameters of type String which I will call from c++.

I am using a maven project, I am not able to create the dll out of my java code, I am using graalvm to convert my java code to dll.

My java code looks like this:

```
package demo;

import org.graalvm.nativeimage.IsolateThread;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.function.CEntryPoint;

public class MyClass{
    
    @CEntryPoint (name = "myFunc")
    public static byte[] myfunc(IsolateThread thread, String x, String y) {

        // logic goes here

        byte[] arr = "byte array will contain actual bytes".getBytes();
        
        return arr;
    }
```

but when I try to build the code into dll, I got this error

> Error: Entry point method parameter types are restricted to primitive types, word types and enumerations (@CEnum): demo.MyClass.myFunc(IsolateThread, String, String)

I searched but didn't find suitable solutions to this problem.
can anyone here please tell me how to call java methods from c++ with non-primitive datatypes
any suggestions of any kind will be a great help, thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are specific preconditions that a java method needs to fulfill in order to run successfully from C or C++ in GraalVM.
These preconditions should be taken into account when designing the Java entry point methods that are going to be annotated with `@CEntryPoint`. The following preconditions are mentioned [in the CEntryPoint documentation](https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/org/graalvm/nativeimage/c/function/CEntryPoint.html).

1. The Java entry point method is only allowed to include primitive Java types, word values and enums. Also in order to actually use an `Enum` the `enum class` must have a `CEnum` annotation.[In the CEntryPoint documentation](https://www.graalvm.org/truffle/javadoc/org/graalvm/nativeimage/c/function/CEntryPoint.html).
2. The Java entry point method should be static.
3. The Java entry point method should catch all exceptions, since it should NOT throw ANY exception. In case an exception is not caught, it is printed and then the process is terminated. However the `@CEntryPoint` documentation explicitly mention to catch all exceptions inside the java entry point methods.
4. An `IsolateThread` parameter is required. More precisely

> An execution context must be passed as a parameter and can be either
> an IsolateThread that is specific to the current thread, or an Isolate
> for an isolate in which the current thread is attached. These pointers
> can be obtained via the methods of CurrentIsolate. When there is more
> than one parameter of these types, exactly one of the parameters must
> be annotated with CEntryPoint.IsolateThreadContext for IsolateThread,
> or CEntryPoint.IsolateContext for Isolate.

The sample in your question throws this error since the `myFunc` method signature includes objects, for instance the `String` parameters. Namely `x` and `y`. This is not allowed according to the precondition **1** from above. This is what the error description tries to say.

The solution is to use the functionality provided to convert between Java types and C types. In this case in order to pass text between `C` and `Java` we can use a [`CCharPointer`](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/nativeimage/c/type/CCharPointer.html). Since text is modeled differently in `C` and `Java`, a `Java String` must be converted to `C *char` and vice versa.

**Creating and returning a Java String**

There is an example below that can be used when `byte[]` represents text.

```
//These are the imports needed
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type.CCharPointer;
import org.graalvm.nativeimage.c.type.CTypeConversion;

@CEntryPoint(name = "myFunc")
  public static CCharPointer myFunc(IsolateThread thread, CCharPointer x, CCharPointer y) {
        //Convert C *char to Java String
        final String xString= CTypeConversion.toJavaString(x);
        final String yString= CTypeConversion.toJavaString(y);

        //logic goes here

        //Convert Java String to C *char
        try(final CTypeConversion.CCharPointerHolder holder=CTypeConversion.toCString("Hello from Java")){
        
                final CCharPointer result=holder.get();
                return result;
         }
        
  }
```

**Using and returning an array allocated in C**

You can also follow a C style and pass as an argument an array in C and then use this array to write the result byte values in Java. The method [CCharPointer.write(int,byte)](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/nativeimage/c/type/CCharPointer.html#write-int-byte-) can write `Java byte` values to specific array indexes in the `*char` or `char[]`. The byte array can also be returned, if needed.

```
@CEntryPoint(name = "myFunc2")
  public static CCharPointer myFunc2(IsolateThread thread
         , CCharPointer x, CCharPointer y                                                                                  
         , CCharPointer resultArray, int resultArrayLength) {

        //Convert C *char to Java String
        final String xString= CTypeConversion.toJavaString(x);
        final String yString= CTypeConversion.toJavaString(y);

        //logic goes here

        //Fill in the result array
        final byte sampleByteValue=7;
        for(int index =0; index<resultArrayLength; index++){
        resultArray.write(index, sampleByteValue);
        }
        return resultArray;
  }
```

**Using a [Java NIO ByteBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html)**

For larger byte arrays you can check [CTypeConversion](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/nativeimage/c/type/CTypeConversion.html#asByteBuffer-org.graalvm.word.PointerBase-int-) that can create a [`Java NIO ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) with a specific capacity that refers to the native memory. Note that

> the caller is responsible for ensuring that the memory can be safely
> accessed while the ByteBuffer is used, and for freeing the memory
> afterwards.

Comment: first of all, thank you so much, I understand the conversion of string type between java and c++. in my case the byte[] will not contain texts it will contain bytes only, will it work for that also?

Comment: You are welcome. Yes, I will update my answer to include an example.

Comment: my byte array will be huge, can i write my entire byte array at once only or do I have to write it at a specific index only?

Comment: You can use a ByteBuffer to perform more array operations. I added it in the description. Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: I am not getting how to use the byte buffer, and i have one more doubt can I pass object between java and C++?

Comment: Using the NIO Byte Buffer is a topic on its own, perhaps a different question as NIO is something independent from GraalVM. You can try something in a new question and if possible I could help. See for instance here https://www.javarticles.com/2018/04/java-nio-bytebuffer.html Passing objects is not possible, as stated in precondition 1 in my answer and the javadoc, The closest you could get is using an independent format e.g. JSON and marshalling/unmarshalling as needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222176/discussion-between-sahil-verma-and-spyros-k).

Comment: Hi again your answer worked, I am having a problem with the encoding type. Actually, I need a base64 encoded string but I don't know what encoding does the CTypeConversion uses because I am not able to decode it using a base64 decoder into a byte array, can you please help me with that?